# Subsetting data frame in R based on specific indices of original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to create a new `dataframe` object from an original `dataframe`, and want to do so by selecting indices that are relevant for my condition. Say, my `dataframe` has a variable called `subjectnumber`, and I want to create my new `dataframe` which includes only the rows where the `subjectnumber` belongs to this list `c(2,4,6,7,8)` for instance.

This is what I want to implement, in short:

```
new.dataframe <- subset(old.dataframe(for (old.dataframe$subjectnumber == c(2,4,6,7,8))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `df` is your old dataframe:

```
new.df = df[df$subjectnumber %in %c(2,4,6,7,8),]
```

**Example:**

```
df = data.frame(col1=1:10, col2=letters[1:10])

#   col1 col2
#1     1    a
#2     2    b
#3     3    c
#4     4    d
#5     5    e
#6     6    f
#7     7    g
#8     8    h
#9     9    i
#10   10    j

df[df$col1 %in% c(2,3,6,10,8),]

#   col1 col2
#2     2    b
#3     3    c
#6     6    f
#8     8    h
#10   10    j
```